# Making the right post request

Tags: python, html

I need your help in putting together a post request.
The output I get is html, but the plan was to get the following:
[image]

Below are all the data for the desired item:

General

```
Request URL: https://dgslivebetting.betonline.ag/ngwbet.aspx/gvFrameHtml
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200
Remote Address: 104.17.64.19:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Response Headers

```
cache-control: no-cache
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 76800ae95afc35b3-DME
content-encoding: br
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Thu, 10 Nov 2022 16:07:42 GMT
expires: -1
pragma: no-cache
server: cloudflare
set-cookie: server_persistent=!zk3OrErnBetHZkiKJcby5Il79pzHsf7dxKD0PcVuB54Z2dznuEbqgGAVDWLDvoqpVSDnVq+Jtf91LHo=; path=/; Httponly; Secure
x-newrelic-app-data: PxQFUFRTDQMHR1NRBQkOVVABDhFORDQHUjZKA1ZLVVFHDFYPHjZWADdTRRcPAF0cXgMWAFJFaAcXQU4cBRAlEFEPXSpMVVgQH1UXUR1RHVBUAA9QVloUHgFIQ1YCAg9fAAgFAFZXUFYDUQBAFF5VXkAAZA==
```

Request Headers

```
:authority: dgslivebetting.betonline.ag
:method: POST
:path: /ngwbet.aspx/gvFrameHtml
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
content-length: 12
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
cookie: \_xpid=574830729; \_xpkey=K_F3GRHECOTdjT306mOafHByLTxopGhY; LPVID=MxZmQyM2Q5OTFlOTU0ZTJk; \_hjSessionUser_2115245=eyJpZCI6IjQ3MzAxYmQwLTQ4ODgtNWNjMC1hZGZjLWJlZDBmNDgwZDJjZCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NjY1NTY0MjQwOTIsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; CT.CONTENT.NA.STATUS=1; \_gid=GA1.2.1666042031.1667883501; PreviousUrlNav=%2Fsportsbook%2Flive-betting; chQuickBet=undefined; inputAmount=100.00; kameleoonVisitorCode=\_js_ti27yqxpj7dd4k1x; DD-LINK-NAREDIRECT=0; ASP.NET_SessionId=5acflzzgqtjdvsnjc5wtwuys; tz=Eastern%20Standard%20Time; btpdb.1PR3l09.dGZjLjY2ODI2ODU=U0VTU0lPTg; oddsfmt=dec; \_hjSession_2115245=eyJpZCI6Ijk2NzBiMjNkLWY4MGQtNDM5OS1hYWNhLWQyODBjNmZlYzNkMSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NjgwOTM2NzY4OTUsImluU2FtcGxlIjpmYWxzZX0=; \_hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; \_hjIncludedInSessionSample=0; LPSID-90263191=bLgFHbiuTjOcwCg1FgR16g; \__cf_bm=5LozQOf4P4COCn1rVD5emsVzukFSNbWdS7kvBVodzJ4-1668096251-0-AQ+nY5HeihIwV+gAI1oaFKJJxOtgXWs5czIr198Ffrh18P1q4nriEcszp/j7dwjuDjVuki1jlT6IByy2ewOCcXSUWavF+3MCcBF4Yb8sfDPVkvoSufxJ46feYuPiCiPcw0eW9oTUnrmZNcEkZ1732RDx6LWq1OElUvT0Uk6sk1n1; \_gat_UA-190679354-1=1; \_ga_KC6V6402HY=GS1.1.1668096234.18.1.1668096460.0.0.0; \_ga=GA1.1.1142263304.1666556424; server_persistent=!Tdbrpsz3tJ8jlNmKJcby5Il79pzHsfLVz91fFnDrXObiJE45d6idCUAVcW4Qmd/g598vNFaqTVuVRvk=
origin: https://dgslivebetting.betonline.ag
referer: https://dgslivebetting.betonline.ag/ngwbet.aspx
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
x-newrelic-id: VgcFUVNTDxACV1NaDgIDVlw=
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

Please help me figure out how I can get what I want.

My code:

```
import requests
import cloudscraper


scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

url = 'https://dgslivebetting.betonline.ag/ngwbet.aspx/gvFrameHtml'
data = {"gameID":0}
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)   Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    'Referer': "https://dgslivebetting.betonline.ag/ngwbet.aspx/gvFrameHtml"
}

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Have you tried `r.json`? What is the output of `r.text`?

Comment: when I print(r.text) I get the html page.

Comment: What does the page look like? Can you provide an example?

Comment: With r.json I get <bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>> but I don't see it.

Comment: `r.json()` - my bad. It's a method not an attribute

Comment: Do you mean html code?

Comment: Yes. Does the HTML contain the data you need, but you just can't extract it easily?

Comment: Also, your first image has data returned in a `JSON` format, which suggests that calling`.json()` might be the way to go.

Comment: The html does not contain the data I need. I cannot access all the elements inside the html because they simply are not there, they are deeper. The task now is to make a request and get the necessary element.

Comment: print(r.json()) ends with error: requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

Comment: What do you mean by _deeper_? It could be the case that the website doesn't allow web-scraping

Comment: What I mean is that I can't access the necessary items that are further down the tree.

Comment: By the way, about print(r.json()). json() takes parameters, perhaps you need to specify something to solve the issue. Please advise.

Comment: Could you be more specific? _I can't access the necessary items that are further down the tree_ doesn't make a lot of sense to me. If they are further down the tree, why can't they be accessed?

Comment: `r.json()` returns a dictionary, not sure what parameters you could be referencing?

Comment: because I can't get the full html code of the page because the site is protected by cloudflare, or because of my little knowledge in this matter.

Comment: I think you'll have to wait for a different developer to come and see if there's a way through this. My hunch is that either `cloudscraper` does not work on the site for some reason or has a limit for the size of the HTML returned. If the data aren't there, then there's not much you can do to make it appear. I'd change the title and description of the question to add more details and be as specific as possible for when someone new can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get JSON back, you need to add the `Content-Type` header to your request.

Your current examples shows you are only sending these headers:

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)   Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    'Referer': "https://dgslivebetting.betonline.ag/ngwbet.aspx/gvFrameHtml"
}
```

At the very least, you'll need to add `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` to the request, otherwise, `requests` is doing an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form post which is why you're getting back HTML from this site instead of JSON.

Comment: I tried your approach earlier, but got an error 500

Comment: If you have a chance, test it for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, it all worked out, thank you.